# "Your Hats" is unreadable

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash-2016

The corner of the hat dialog has the title "Your Hats," but the dark grey text is unreadable on a dark blue background:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if there's a secret hat awarded for discovering this obscure text. ;)

Comment: The answer is no

Comment: Nice cat avatar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice catch and thanks for reporting! Just committed a fix that should make this text readable, like so:

[image]